# An exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I have follow layers in my project:

1. LifeExpress.Domain : contain Domain Classs
2. LifeExpress.Business : it contain class for crud operations.
3. LifeExpress.services : It is WCF layer, to communicate with web and business layer.
4. LifeExpress.Web : for view.

on My Business layer I have written this code

```
   public IList<Tools> getAllTools()
   {
       using (LifeExpressContext lifeExpressContext = new LifeExpressContext())
       {
           var tools = lifeExpressContext.tools.ToList();
           return tools;
       }
   }
```

This method is called from My service layer which is called from web layer.

I have added the reference to `EntityFramework.dll`  and  `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` on every layer.

But when I try to get the records from database , It gives me error

> An exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9489971. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted

this is my app.config file code on Business layer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LifeExpressContext" connectionString="Data Source=AMIT-PC;Initial Catalog=LifeExpressApp;User ID=sa;Password=12345" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

this is my config file code for WCF layer

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Obviously something is unreachable. You don't even tell us if it's DataBase access or WCF service. It's useless to tell us about both, and describe your architecture : go straight to the point ! According error message I guess it's probably WCF. Have you tried to run your program in debug mode to get full stacktrace ? Have you tried to open your database with a client (SSMS) ? Your WCF services with a browser ? Are you sure to have started both WCF service AND client ?

Comment: And of course `lifeExpressContext.tools.ToList()` could contain too many records to collect in the available time. Can you get a very small selection as a proof of concept?